# Setting up my touchpad to be one big button?

Tags: windows, touchpad

I'm forced to use Windows for a while, and I need some set up to work with my machine in a way I'm used to. 
I've got Asus N750Jv, which has a "mac"-style big touchpad, which is devided into 2 areas - left button & right button.

What I want to achieve is basically mac-like touchpad, but not from point of gestures & such, but from a point of usability.

This includes mostly having whole touchpad as one big button, that doesn't react to tapping, but only to clicking. 1 finger click = left button, 2 finger click = right button, etc.

I can not achieve this with drivers Asus gives me: I don't have option to set a touchpad as one big button. Can anything be done with this?

Thanks,

Mike.

Answer (score 0):

With touchpads I have used, you can change the width of the "right" portion of the touchpad.

If you can't change this setting for your current laptop, you could get a portable keyboard with a touchpad, and hopefully it would give you greater control over the settings.

I'm not sure what the difference between tap and click is (I'm lost on a Mac), but I know that in Windows 7 you can change the settings of Windows Explorer so that you don't need to do double-taps.  (That may be irrelevant to what you're looking for -- but I wanted to include it just in case.)

Comment: Well unfortunately Asus bundled tool doesn't allow that. On Linux (my main system) I run generic drivers for touchpad called synaptics. This driver allows any possible configurations I'd want. Does such thing exist for windows?

Comment: My touchpad uses synaptics, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this on the net:

> I have figured out how to disable the right click, but on the latest
>   asus elantech driver (V11.5.11.3 ) instead. There is a registry
>   setting for it called ClickPad_RightCorner_Click_Enable
>
> However, ClickPad_Three_Finger_Click_Enable doesn't seem to work. I
>   have disabled the three finger tapping thing, but it still opens up
>   notepad or acts like only two fingers are pressed (right click context
>   menu)

Solution to be tested yet, though.